# Filter a larger DataFrame using date ranges from a smaller one

Tags: python, pandas

Fairly new to pandas so I'm struggling with this.

I have a larger DataFrame with records indexed by a MultiIndex containing a DatetimeIndex, and a smaller DataFrame indexed with start and end dates, both of DatetimeIndex also. Here's what they look like:

Larger DataFrame:

```
                       Data
PatId EntryDate  Id                                        
725   2005-01-03 1422  X
      2005-01-04 1563  X
      2005-01-05 1355  X
      2005-01-06 118   X
      2005-01-09 1400  X
```

And the smaller one containing the date ranges:

```
                         PatId
EntryDate  ExitDate          
2005-01-15 2005-04-15   22407
2005-01-30 2005-04-30   95938
2005-02-07 2005-05-07  116812
2005-02-18 2005-05-18   12163
2005-02-21 2005-05-21   22908
```

**I'd like an elegant and efficient way to filter the larger DataFrame to only include those records that fall within the date ranges defined in the smaller DataFrame.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
EntryDate = df2.index.get_level_values('EntryDate')
ExitDate = df2.index.get_level_values('ExitDate')

idx = np.concatenate([pd.date_range(s, e) for s, e in zip(EntryDate, ExitDate)])
df = df1[df1.index.get_level_values('EntryDate').isin(np.unique(idx))]
```

**Explanation**:

1. First get values of `MultiIndex` by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html)
2. Create [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html)s in loop and join together
3. Last filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only by `unique` datetimes

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple process like this:

```
pd.concat([df.loc[:, start:end] for start, end in zip(df2.EntryDate, df2.ExitDate)])
```

**Explanation**

- DataFrames allow for slicing using datetime or a string format parsable as datetime
- You need to filter the dataframe into smaller parts and then concatenate it
- The rest is a simply list comprehension

Comment: This looks pretty neat - thanks. I modified it slightly to use the index values with `get_level_values` and I'm getting a `ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing`. Any ideas why? My indexes are sorted...